# Why do Glide only work on raw string url data? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, string, url, kotlin, android-glide

I can successfully use a string url with glide to get the image I want:

```
glideVariable!!.loadImageUrl("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/healthandchocolate-46f3d.appspot.com/o/cookies%2FcookiesImg1.jpg?alt=media&token=63721d7d-207e-441c-9387-14dced13d3c8")
```

but when I try to use the very same url, stored in a variable, the image doesn't load:

```
glideVariable!!.loadImageUrl(recipeArray[1].recipeImage.toString())
```

I have done a `Log.d` on `recipeArray[1].recipeImage.toString()` and it does indeed contain the very same url that worked on my first example, using raw string data.

I have used escape commands to encapsulate the variable in quotation marks like this:

```
glideVariable!!.loadImageUrl("${recipeArray[1].recipeImage.toString()}")
```

but it still doesn't work. I have also tried to cast it as `URL` and `URI`, but still nothing. Any ideas? Can glide only use raw string data?

***UPDATE***
I noted that `recipeArray[1].recipeImage` contain both a `key` and a `value`. Perhaps this is the problem. It doesn't access the url string directly. How do I make sure just to use the string value? It looks like this:

```
DataSnapshot { key = recipeImageFirebase, value = https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/healthandchocolate-46f3d.appspot.com/o/cookies%2FcookiesImg1.jpg?alt=media&token=63721d7d-207e-441c-9387-14dced13d3c8 }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it now. The `recipeArray[1].recipeImage.toString()` was a data snapshot containing both a key and a string. I went back to when I stored the variable:

```
val image = item.child("recipeImageFirebase")

tempRecipe.recipeImage = image.toString()
```

and changed the last part to

```
tempRecipe.recipeImage = image.value.toString()
```

Now it only contains the string value and not the key "recipeImageFirebase" as well!